# How to catch JTree node expanded event

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtree, expand

I seek for a way in SWING JTree similar to SWT's
TreeNode.addListener(SWT.Expand, new Listener()...
I managed to check for last selected node to find selected one, but how may I find which node was expanded and handle it in a proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the (funny named) `TreeWillExpandListener`.

```
TreeWillExpandListener treeWillExpandListener = new TreeWillExpandListener() {
      public void treeWillCollapse(TreeExpansionEvent treeExpansionEvent)
          throws ExpandVetoException {

        TreePath path = treeExpansionEvent.getPath();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();

        //Print the name of the node if toString() was implemented
        String data = node.getUserObject().toString();
        System.out.println("WillCollapse: " + data);

      }

      public void treeWillExpand(TreeExpansionEvent treeExpansionEvent) throws ExpandVetoException {

        TreePath path = treeExpansionEvent.getPath();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();

        //print the name of the node if toString was implemented  
        String data = node.getUserObject().toString();
        System.out.println("WillExpand: " + data);

      }
    };

tree.addTreeWillExpandListener(treeWillExpandListener);
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the missing part, usefull even with standard expand listener. It's the TreePath object along with getLastPathComponent() method giving the last component was in action here.